# What is C# equivalent to ATAN(X,Y)?

Tags: c#, idl-programming-language

It looks like there are two parameters inside the atan function, but I'm not sure how to convert this to C#?

The IDL reference says ***"If two parameters are supplied, the angle whose tangent is equal to Y/X is returned. "***

```
   atan(out[2,*],sqrt(out[0,*]^2+out[1,*]^2))
   atan(out[1,*],out[0,*])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should do it no ?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.atan2.aspx

```
using System;
radians = Math.Atan2(y, x);
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't think to look in the .NET math library, or that such a function even existed :)

Comment: the `atan2` function is an idiom coming from standard C :)